# Ingresar array de objetos

Tags: php, json, array

tengo un JSON con la siguiente estructura:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [13223] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [entity_id] => 13223
                    [status] => payment
```

Este JSON se repite de forma que tengo índices por un total de 5 elementos, he tratado de entrar y recuperar el valor entity_id, pero no logro como reconocer el valor [13223] ya que este valor cambia ya que proviene de un Magento.

He tratado con `$prueba = $decode[0];` lo cual me abre el primer elemento del array, quedando así

```
stdClass Object
(
    [13223] => stdClass Object
        (
            [entity_id] => 13223
            [status] => payment
            [coupon_code] =>
```

La duda es como logro llegar hasta el entity_id.

El siguiente es un extracto un poco mas completo, ya que excedo los 60k caracteres.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [13223] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [entity_id] => 13223
                    [status] => payment
                    [coupon_code] => 
                    [shipping_description] => Envio gratis - Contraentrega
                    [customer_id] => 39707
                    [discount_amount_from_original_price] => 0.0000
                    [base_discount_amount] => 0.0000
                    [base_grand_total] => 96.0000
                    [base_shipping_amount] => 0.0000
                    [base_shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
 [bottler_data] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [route_code] => FALCON_MONTERREY
                            [postalcode] => 64600
                            [delivery_date] => 2019-11-23 00:00:00
                            [website] => Falcon
                            [store] => Falcon
                            [storeview] => Falcon
                            [cedi_name] => Falcon
                        )
 [is_subscription] => 
                    [delivery_comments] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [13224] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [entity_id] => 13224
                    [status] => pending
                    [coupon_code] => 
                    [shipping_description] => Envio gratis - Contraentrega
                    [customer_id] => 39707
                    [discount_amount_from_original_price] => 0.0000
                    [base_discount_amount] => 0.0000
                    [base_grand_total] => 672.0000
                    [base_shipping_amount] => 0.0000
                    [base_shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
```

Comment: Puedes llegar al dato haciendo algo así: `$prueba->13223->entity_id` la cuestión clave aquí es saber si la clave padre o sea esto: `[13223] => stdClass Object` se llama siempre `13223` o esto puede variar. Ese es el *quid*  del asunto, porque es esa clave la que te acceso a los otros elementos. Si eso varía quizá sea necesario que el JSON sea organizado de otro modo en el origen o usar un bucle para leer los datos sin conocer las claves de entrada.

Comment: No me funcionó, como lorge ingresar al valor es usando { } quedando asi: $prueba = $decode[0]->{13223}->entity_id; Lamentablemente la documentación del API no especifica si es valor es fijo ya que proviene de una web con Magento, por lo que sigo sin saber como obtener el valor del padre

Comment: Sería bueno que muestres la estructura completa del JSON para ver si podemos ayudarte mejor.